# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+4n}\right)^{2n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The problem:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+4n}\right)^{2n+1}$$

[image: Part of my solution]

Hey, I need to find the sequence limit, I got to this point by adding n-n to the numerator, so I got e formula, but I don't know if I am allowed to separate and to calculate the limit only for what I left in the power.
Also I would glad to see other methods to solve this (I tried first to divide in the biggest power but it didn't work for me)

Comment: The standard way to approach $1^\infty$ indeterminate forms is to take logarithms to change them into $\infty\cdot0$ indeterminate forms, then use appropriate procedures for those (such as rewriting into a l'Hôpital's rule form).

Comment: So the question is, can you apply l'Hôpital's rule as @GregMartin suggests?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\left(\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+4n}\right)^{2n+1}=\left[\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n^2+4n}\right)^{\frac{n^2+4n}{n-1}}\right]^{(2n+1)\frac{n-1}{n^2+4n}}$$

Observe that inside the square parentheses you have an expression of the form $\;(1-bn)^{1/b_n}\;$ , with $\;b_n\to 0\;$ . Take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+4n}=1+\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+4n}-1=1+\frac{\frac{1-n}{n+4}}{n}$$

Notice that
$$a_n:=\frac{1-n}{n+4}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}-1$$
and
$$\Big(\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+4n}\Big)^{2n+1}=\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+4n}\left(\Big(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\Big)^n\right)^2\,
$$